# ASP.NET MVC Html.DropDownListFor Select value

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have a little problem. I use the Html.DropDownListFor helper to render a dropdown list to the client.

But I can't set the selected value in dropdown list.

```
<%= Html.DropDownListFor(model => Model.CalculationClassCollection, 
new SelectList(Model.CalculationClassCollection, "ID", "Name",  3 ), 
new { id = "ddCalculationClass" })%>
```

Anybody can help me?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the SelectList is not a member of my Model, I'd use `<%= Html.DropDownList("listBoxID", new SelectList(Model.CalculationClassCollection, "ID", "Name", 3 ))%>`

Answer (score 0):

It is one of the overloaded methods. I think it is the method with a parameter something like default. Sorry I am not in front of dev PC right now so I can't tell you exactly which method it is.